# Nautilus Global Settings

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I'm trying to figure out a way to set a flag on Nautilus for all/new users. It's just set `always_use_browser` to `True`. I didn't find any way to set it globally, just locally. I spent hours doing a workaround which uses gconftool-2, but to solve this issue, I think it could be more simple than applying and avoid resources usage to run my (dirty) solution.

Does Gnome have file/command to set this nautilus flag (`always_use_browser=True`) globally?

Comment: Finally, I found a solution.

gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/ --type boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_browser true

Answer (score 1):

- Check whether you have 'always_use_browser' property supported in the files.  `/usr/share/nautilus/glade/nautilus-file-management-properties.glade`.
- Schema should be supporting it: `/etc/gconf/schemas/apps_nautilus_preferences.schemas`

Make sure you take a backup before editing any of these xml files.

- Use `gconftool-2`

Open GConf Editor (GUI mode):

```
               (Menu > System > Configuration > Gnome > Advanced)

               Expand: Apps > Nautilus > Preferences

               Put A Check Next To "always_use_browser"
```

Or Alternatively from the command line mode (CLI):

```
[centos@centos glade]$ gconftool-2  -T --get /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_browser
false
bool
```

Set the value to `true`

```
[centos@centos glade]$ sudo gconftool-2 --type bool  --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_browser true
[centos@centos glade]$ sudo gconftool-2   --get /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_browser 
true
[centos@centos glade]$
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nikhil. I found a way to use gconftool-2 globally. The problem of modifying a Nautilus project file is the warrant of functioning, mainly after a nautilus update.

Comment: @manoelhc You are welcome :-)

Comment: I would suggest to execute this command on behalf of everyone since the already existing users's personal gconf db settings would overwrite the global settings.

Comment: You can look for other useful settings at http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/gconf-8.html.en#gconf-16